# Winsock failed to connect to local ip address

Tags: sockets, vb6, tcp, network-programming, winsock

I have used the following code in a form that acts like a server,

```
WskServer(0).Close  
LocalIP = WskServer(0).LocalIP  
WskServer(0).LocalPort = DEFAULT_TCP_PORT  
WskServer(0).Protocol = sckTCPProtocol  
txtStatus.Text = "Starting server"  
Call WskServer(0).Bind(DEFAULT_TCP_PORT, LocalIP)  
WskServer(0).Listen
```

when i execute above code,i received the following error
**"Address is not available from the local machine"** .

If i changed the line

```
Call WskServer(0).Bind(DEFAULT_TCP_PORT, LocalIP)
```

to

```
Call WskServer(0).Bind(DEFAULT_TCP_PORT, "127.0.0.1")  this is working
```

What's wrong with the code?, can anybody give the fix

**Update**
I just removed the line Call WskServer(0).Bind(DEFAULT_TCP_PORT, LocalIP) now server working properly. this way is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

check whether in etc.host file in system32 directory the localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1

Comment: all lines commented in hosts file

Comment: can you try uncommenting the localhost line?